# Outputting errors when executing SQL scripts in Sqlplus

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have a number of huge .SQL files that inserts data into tables. I'm using Sqlplus to execute these scripts. While the command window is crunching all these thousands of `INSERT INTO {table}` statements, I occasionally see an error showing up in the command window for a split second before Sqlplus goes on to the next `INSERT INTO {table}` statement.

Is there a way to show any error that comes up after executing a SQL script in Sqlplus?

Comment: have you tried `spool`ing the output?

Comment: Took a look at spool-ing, put it in my SQL script and it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from spooling you could use error logging feature with DML. This link gives you details
[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables004.htm)

Comment: SPOOL was exactly what I needed. Thanks.